# Angular Router: Why do I get a value from queryParams but not from paramMap?

Tags: angular, angular-router

So I have a service in my angular app that is injected when I navigate to my route `soquestion/:id`. In the constructor of the service I have the following code:

```
constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
  ) {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe((params: any) => console.log(params));
    this.route.params.subscribe((params: any) => console.log(params));
    
  }
```

The first subscription prints a value in the console while the second is never firing at all and I do not understand why because if I navigate to `soquestion/1234` there is clearly a param. In another component this is working just fine but for some reason the service does not want to fire the subscription at all.

Am I overlooking something?

Comment: How your url looks like?

Comment: example would be:  localhost:4200/soquestion/1234

Comment: In a service there is no activated route (only in components). You can use `Router` to subscribe to `events` and traverse the routes tree to find the params

Comment: @MichaelDoye this should be the answer

Comment: @MichaelDoye Genuine question: How comes I can subscribe to the queryParams then and receive the expected value from the ActivatedRoute? Will try your suggestion and see if that makes it work.

Comment: When your service initialises, the route does not exist in the route tree. queryParams are shared by all routes while params are scoped to a specific route which is why you can access queryParams and not params. Another option is to pass the `ActivatedRoute` instance to your service from the component.